# Where is exit command file in Linux?

Tags: linux, command, exit

Most of the commands are stored in /bin directory of Linux, but I am not able to find exit command. Where is the exit command file stored?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Ask how to solve the actual problem you are working on and include your code so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know where does specific command come from `which` is your friend. Eg under zsh you will see the following message

```
> which exit
exit: shell built-in command
```

If you want to change command name use alias

```
> alias foobar=exit
```

If you want to change command name and disable old name, use alias once again:

```
> alias exit=barfoo
> exit
zsh: command not found: barfoo
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a binary - it's one of the shell functions.  What are you looking to do with it?

Comment: actually i am making a sandbox,and im changing all the command names,
i also wanted to change the name of exit command,
but since i am not able to find its location i wasnt able to do the renaming.so now please can you tell me how do i rename it

Comment: My first thought was using alias, but that still leaves the original command in place.  An alternative option is to build your own version of bash (or whatever shell you're using).  This will, however, break large amounts of system scripts...

Answer (score 0):

`exit` is a shell built-in command, not a separate executable. So when you type `exit` you actually don't tell the shell to find and execute an `exit` file, but just close the shell.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shell built-in, just like some other commands such as `alias`, `echo`, `help`, `printf` or `read`.